# How can I use cookies to prevent a pop up with colorbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cookies, colorbox

I'm using Colorbox with an iframe for a 15 second pop-up on a website. The iframe would be an email subscription to blog post updates. I would like to prevent the pop-up if someone has already subscribed. Is there a way to do this with colorbox and an iframe?

I'm sure I'll have to create cookies, which I've never done. I'm just not sure if its even possible since its an iframe but I would like to ask. Maybe, another 3rd party plugin may be best for this kind of request. Any ideas?

This is all I have right now, I haven't even created the iframe yet. I just don't want to code eveything without this even working.

```
function openColorBox(){
  $.colorbox({
    iframe: true, 
    width: "80%", 
    height: "80%", 
    href: "http://www.mommyinmilwaukee.com/"
  });
}      
setTimeout(openColorBox, 15000);
```

Comment: what about using modals like in JQueryUI or Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: Im using Bootstrap on the site, so that would work. Can I set up a modal to pop-up and cookies to not pop-up after an email subscription?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use Bootstrap Modal, still dont know how to add cookies but thats another topic. I just made the with Bootstrap. Thanks,